# Question about the second derivative of functions at a local max/min

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Is the following true :
If $f(x)$ is a twice differentiable function with a local maximum/minimum at a.  The  function $g(x)$=$d^2f\over d^2x$ will attain its local minimum/maximum at a

---

Q: is the above statement true if so how would you prove it?  If not what function would be a counter- example 
For most functions it seems to be true and if we had to prove it somehow i think you would have to use some property form analysis . By the second derivative test the sign of $g(x)$ is clear but it does not tell anything else .And maybe you would have to use the fact that $f’(a)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a counterexample, consider $f(x)=x^3-x$ and $a=1/\sqrt{3}$. Then $f$ has a local minimum at $a$ but $f''(x)=6x$, so $f''$ does not have any minima or maxima.

Answer (score 0):

The  function $f(x)$ will attain its local minimum/maximum at at $x=a$. Not its second derivative.

Second derivative sign $ (>0,<0) $ respectively determines whether the touching U shape sits on x-axis as minimum or hangs down from it as maximum.

Comment: But what is a counter example that the second derivative does not also attain a min/max at a ?

Comment: When discussing multiple root we do not deal with the third derivative, for max/min of second derivative of $f(x).$